# There is no way to screenshot background of view?

Tags: android, capture

I want to make a android app that have background is blurred-HomeScreen.

Like a iOS do usually.

So I make app that

1. App launching with transparent Activity.

   1. (transparent Activity) capture whole screen and save into sd card for png file.
2. Process blurred image of step 2.
3. Start mainActivity with blurred image of step 3.

But, at Step 2, my app just captured transparent image.

There is no way to capture HomeScreen without rooting?

Comment: Nope.  THis is for security-  they don't want random apps to be able to take pictures of the screen that could contain personal information-  passwords, bank account details, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html

```
WallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

Comment: So, if you upvote my answer, I think it is good. Can you make it as Resolved (green symbole) ? and the comment of GabeSechan is not good ?